# xmlReadMemory not preserving empty nodes in original format

Tags: c, linux, libxml2

I am using libxml2 with C for parsing a `const char *` which is in XML format. When I create `xmlDocPtr` for this string (using `xmlReadMemory(..)`), the resulting `xmlDocPtr` does not preserve empty nodes (`<tag></tag>`) in their original form. It consolidates each pair in a single tag (`<tag/>`). In my case, it is creating problem.
Is there any way to preserve these empty nodes in their original form?
I see the 'options' argument in `xmlReadMemory()`, but not really sure whether at all I can use it for this purpose.

Comment: In which way you need to use the xmlDocPtr ? You need to use it for saving a file or you parse it? Why you need to have both tags?

Comment: After getting the xmlDocPtr I am taking a dump (xmlNodeDump) of it. I am going to use a part of the dump (as char *) for further processing, at a later point of time in my program.

Comment: Take a look at this function xmlKeepBlanksDefault() here: http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlKeepBlanksDefault

Answer (score 0):

> It consolidates each pair in a single tag (). In my case, it is creating problem.

For what it's worth, that's relying on something that's not guaranteed with XML.  The spec says, "The representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag, or an empty-element tag."

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags

Any conforming XML parser should see either representation as the same thing.  I don't know if it's possible to change whatever code is relying on it, but that would be the most "correct" solution.

I know sometimes these things are out of our control, just wanted to bring up the idea.